# Do returned cards go to the back of the deck?

Tags: hearthstone

At the beginning of a Hearthstone match, you can choose to either keep or discard your starting hand. If you discard cards, are they placed at the back of the deck or are they shuffled before the game begins allowing them to (possibly) come out in early draws.

Answer (score 0):

Mulliganed cards are shuffled back into your deck after you have drawn the new ones. This means that you cannot draw the card you discarded with your replacement cards (though if you have a second copy you can draw that).

Since it is shuffled in, you can draw it at any point in the game, including, if you are very unfortunate, your first turn.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, they are. And you can pay attention to how many cards your opponent discards, if they discard none, then they probably have a good opening hand.

Comment: Yes they are what?

Comment: @Mondrianaire: Sent to the back of the deck. He's referring to the question title. And for the record, this means his answer is wrong. Studoku's is correct.